# How do i configure django urls to make it so if it displays 404, it reroutes to Reactjs

Tags: django, reactjs, django-views, react-router, django-urls

The title is terrible - sorry about that.

So say I have a website say www.myhairynose.com/. I've configured my urls.py so that whenever the person enters www.myhairynose.com it redirects them to the index.html (where it displays the reactjs application). I've set reactjs with react-router and made it so when you click a button on the index page it goes to www.myhairynose.com/#/webpage.

Thing is... I don't want that.

I want it to go to www.myhairnose.com/webpage. I want react to handle this however and not django. ALL of this url thing should be in the same application of index.html. How do I configure django urls.py so that if I enter www.myhairynose.com/webpage it goes to the index of www.myhairnose.com ReactJs's application and then it checks to see if the route has webpage. Otherwise say if I went to www.myhairynose.com/asdkjaskldsaj (which the react route doesn't have) it should display a 404.

______TLDR______
Basically what I want to happen:

```
User goes to website.com/name
>if website.com/name exists in django - it returns a html doc
>if not then it redirects to website.com/ where ReactJs will handle the url and see if it matches any of the routers
...> if it does, then it displays that route
...> if not then it displays a django 404 or a custom 404 page.
```

How do I configure django and reactjs to do this?

Comment: I found a work around but I'm not sure if this is the correct standard or method of doing this. I hardcoded each react.js route link into my urls.py pointed each of the urls to the home template. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Django to render react? I am making the assumption that you have some view like `views.LoadReactView`.

What you need is a catch all route.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', views.LoadReactView.as_view()),
]
```

This should appear as your very last pattern. You essentially are saying "after checking all the other routes, if there are no matches, go here".

In addition, you could also actually just define your main view as your [404 handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

handler404 = views.LoadReactView.as_view
```

Comment: r'^*' returned some kind of error, do you mean r'^'?

Comment: when I add r'^' it doesn't allow me to access my other urls like /admin

Comment: Sorry, fixed answer. As for `/admin`, as I said, this pattern needs to be the VERY last one. I am adding the admin line to my answer for clarity.

Comment: yeah I put it at the very end but /admin redirects to my home page instead.

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^message/', views.message, name="message"),
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
]`

Comment: ignore about - idk how to edit comments to make the format look better

Comment: Looks fine. Not working? In addition, you could use the method here to specifically define your 404 as your `views.home`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views Updating the answer

Comment: I'm still trying to find the answer. When I have a url(r'^', views.XXX ) on my url list, it doesn't matter where it is in the list (last, first), the other urls don't work (such as /admin, and /polls). All of the urls point the r'^' index.html. How do I make it so react handles all of the urls that are not handled by django?

Comment: found the answer - django requires a trailing slash. So www.XXXX.com/admin wasn't working for me but www.XXX.com/admin/ was